# How to set a negative bias value for light in order to remove the shadow problem?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow-mapping

In our game, we use spine characters which is a 2D mesh. The shadow of the spine characters isn't tightly next to the mesh of spine characters where there always has a crack despite I have already set the bias value to 0. It's so weird.

I try to set the bias value to 0, the crack is smaller but still exist.
So I want to set the bias value to negative value in order to fix it.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You can't set a negative bias.

Comment: what else way can I fix this issue?